# How should I be encoding dates and times?

Tags: vega-lite

I'm converting date columns from an internal date/time format to something Vega-Lite can parse, and am uncertain what my target should be.  In version 4, there was a [date time definition](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite-v4/docs/datetime.html) object, that went something like this `{"year": 2006, "month": "jan", "date": 1}`, and I seem to remember that working.  However some recent plots fail silently when I do that, and I seem to need to use ISO-8601 string formats.

What's the proper way to encode a date and time column in version 5?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a format object with a parse property to parse your dates in whatever format they're in.

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html

> Specific date formats can be provided (e.g., {foo: "date:'%m%d%Y'"}),
> using the d3-time-format syntax.

Comment: I've used data format, thanks.  I guess I'm looking for best practice here.  Since I have to convert from the internal format, I'd like to use whatever format will give me the smoothest path forward when building specifications.