# Why aren't timeUnits working in this example?

Tags: vega-lite

I opened a thread yesterday asking [how I should be encoding dates and times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993681/how-should-i-be-encoding-dates-and-times). It was suggested that the [datetime object](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite-v4/docs/datetime.html) would be a good format, as in 'have the least issues'. Here's an [example where date time doesn't seem to be working](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUGAdlAJZQCe8IA6iSmAGYkBOGIANCAO4AWR8ochgjN4AJgAMARgDsnALYB7Yj3hTOkKGzjqQPRWlFwJCkoTRb4JkFgwBjZWCsBfDcKg8ccGQFZXBYjJKOBo6RhY2Tl5%20BBAhEXFpADYFZQ81DWhtXX1DK1NzS2NOWwdCJ2NXcHdPeABmAE5-ECJSCipaeiZWDm4%20QgE44SNJKR9UlQzwLKnco2t5Mwtta1LHFzdoWrgkmWbWoI6w7si%20mMFhxKkAFgn0nUyinIN5guX8m3t1ys2PLykkvtAu0Qp1wj0ov1BvERtI6ndVA9pk9OHMPotCisSl9yhtqlsvHU-OwAm1gqEuhFetEBrEYVcxAipppsqiXuilkVVjiKhIqmAal4xFIgWSjpSIWdaRcEnBRrolJMkSzZuziiAMe91WtcT98X81HySS1geSwSdqVC6Zc5dIFmlEboVUi0erNVzsWVefzBWokoDjQcQRTwacadCbZIJA0mcqZi61QtOVjPl68QKCWoGkbSYdQccqZDzkNZVGAByxp3x555N3Jj4672-bZlgO54PmwtSiOliQSOQah3M6ts2tJzENnnp306a5l0V5kMWovSkuwiQpQdKqsovSJt4e1PfI367ZSOoLjsFyXh629iTjLf3Hesvdjg8pxvTzNwa7E9tmteYZWjK663E%20jqPK%20rrjlq3JpnqGYGrOl6ARKwHFvStoSPCEHDruMEfpOCEnkh2zXHsgamuKoaWphkZ9oyeFxgR%204avW2pTohM5tiaYr5uhdGrlhUYKkOLHQWx7qflxpEznUF5UfxS5dreoGJH2lZQaq77sROnEkT6P4UahNHLt2d5GFIDQ2VpyKSbp0nEceRnITIOZ8YunY3iBa5Zg0FbMS%20OmvHpcGei5zb-D4HlBmhtErj2Vk2QOirPtpCaORx8GRaeQr%20qZAkJRZ6k6DZm5pZB9khRy%20k5bqcnGf%20nlXoJiWWf5j6VfhDmhU5Bm5WRQpNEpXlAUJSX%20eB3USTVdZ1RFDWuS21yFSpPn0bK1kNLhM3BZlfXZYtTZ5fUa3eRhwk2ttTF7RlNaHQtR5LVFahiGI53je1pXbWJ273aOj3hc9J1DfA2afW1JV%20WVZYxkFANvkDh5ftxP4iqNrXFWpMPWWWqXiftD21cDqONch1kYwBZmqb5WF4xVhOI4RYUo7Jy1CrF1FFeZOP0wFXVM9VB0k2zhmvXAPhUy18W83T10BdNQvOsT82k%20zEuyJD2Py1tAW7crI5I6LMni6dOgbtrcubclZa3YbrFZU9ZMc%20IVu0zbWZln96XC6rsFi4NM7zpjsse1desyIFd1%204DJvOS95sfaHNMbRHyUyAT-2x8bauB4nYNwIp1M8%20Hk1lUk0cO718cDQXM5SMnJfrZd5fWbsdkq3Heem0HP5JE3Mup63HUV4z2dd7nAe9-XP5iM1cXDxNo-WT44%20%205PLP9fVoMN9Li%20l2nbcNNc8Mx5vUlHSD37IWWXPKRdy8-SfSsT0bW9Xy7mvue7R8rztZ9q5zWngnXeP4ZD725i3J%20uMGhiEAW-R2yMZ5gOQkke%20Y0oZ8wVu9Tu79L7Ow1uba4xch6HxHs-KQVdEE1x7qAm%20Z4%20wYKxtbdOWYpA%20yqhfJ26szaFxkKQg%20IAABqigUB2AgIQEgdgAAEEA7CkEQIcb6MNRivw3vgnh%20dUGMMHkI0R4jJHSLkQokgSj2gqJEtIThPVgFETrjowka0DESKkbI%20RijlHQysVIe0NC7GsxQQwwkYhBFQJcUY9xpjzGUEsQxCQ1CNFINrjvYJfpnFiNccYjxZivHYPvFnJJtCQEOLSToSBykIluJMZ4ix3j4nry4Zo5B9C0bIQXuEzJkSam5Lqfk9cgt-EizoaUtp2wwmVK6dUnJMSYFWIkOoppySRmpLGUKDJhjpnRLybrdc9shn%203sas8m2wowbKyVE2psT6l6waIUpZxSjnHTKT4CZi4qnZO2X03Z-lGm2OGSU45rtfznO6TMnZnsyonzwcswFzy1mGgqe8qZnyrlzIVjtGFjzAmtJOV4GyoKtloribc-ZRSAnb3hXitQhLUW9Ouf0-yNjZoAqedfBFOwyxvODB8y59L0W3L8eS1lOLRnUqLty8kvKemzJJbbRJDyKWfyIfw2lfLZU3Ntn8llhzRVAu-tcXi%20iUXqohWw2GgzhW6spey8Vwo77MKlSamVZrj5lkWf861yq%20HyUos3aV4LvmQrxmSxVIqbVf3NueR1VAA1fIZT82GzKibdzhba4F1k9GdM2XSjVjLYZCrDV6whPqfwQxTiEONxLNVZhkAgq1qa2WRsLmISuaqXVBvNdZTOWKlUlr7shYUHTJk5tNZ24%20MhtUpqnk2lVM5rhIp5c6wNCbg13MtUWxteqqXAqzSOi5HbV1doaJXXt4bvUDu2OW-1y740CuSv6M9xbeGXv%20AkkON7R2HvvVmJIG7PVbojXOn8RJh3Iq-Sun9FcPU6sAxe2eyFVoVpEbe6t%20b24GwOXB-tCGzzuTA0uiDd65VZh8DB6dH8cOOPqH6shKGiNocTavTDDaZ3bvTZrGK7bIMkbKj4UNAG2NAdLYOkan6D08ZrXx5NzMCEvtw14OcfZuPEak6vQtgnKPyeo3Ad1KnGNrtPk%207D2mylRhjZW1D-LePWTnMZoT8GdO%20Is-RiTqn0Mv3s1p7RZmjXZrcwZ49dR7mabkz5jlMU-P7rBe5pjO0ZM5280Ejl0aXNVus2pnaGnYMOao2U88SQxN0fS3muL8CvNheS%20KmKynkMlddf-VtFWtFVYzdcJD4mYuBePtZZrLSxXApq2lqzpW103D6ykndmtrjDYYxljzHCJsrKm1GhSBGnVzdG8e6MS203NpnD4Gr%20n5txY3Lt2dIntjuVmwFk7a6cLnfY-t9GtHjWbYa8-CQAmctJdxcCuorZr3FZGx92BmkEaJcq39iWdQXMAFkIBYCwDIpQiAMDyFaDIgAFGAZg5AACUUHRj-p%201DgbmtJVUAR0jlHig0cY%20INj3HBOidwke8J198BDVrWp8j1H6PMc47x4T3joxvsUbJ-qqNUXFy89p-TwXzORdSajPWzduXTMcrqDL4Mcv%20cM6gEz4XrOEns8c-lyQPPEd87pwLxnQuWei77FO2TLXodRsXeSPXtuDdG8dyrvs5HXf9al4XdrVuaf68V8bp3X2zd5Y5egiPNuFf26Vyb7LEu3fk498n%20XdvDcO%20Vx5zFEPuEh5W4XOoC689R7TzHzLcD4%20a-FXUUJteffR-9yXhL5fJscfNq2DvqfC-p5szZTPwf%20-PYpgCYfBe-fF7i3DZv4Xqvrap9b-Pvui9Qbxgq0L2fQ8Nx8K9qB3uR%20L73wFELpOj%20V4bly%20fO%20x%20ZbLCTrPFeB9V9q83C-C-d9x8uVV9WsJZDUdcvct869R8G8PM7YQD3dC4fAishF-8X9YDl9J9Id79v8Dt4coDO969u84sIEECc8q9PdN9I9CCYDiC113IyDj9jI91ZcCDL9ADMs-1GCH854ICqCU8ADX8PMkgWN1dftyCT98DqD2ChC4sB5uDcC54mFn8u8l811DsFCZ9xkVCiC1Cgtb9P9p9gNEMpCBD0C6Dj0xhNDjDtg14dDaC9CessC%209ltFC0EWDdc2DBCMD7sD878v8tDCRKcQg0DVDr8HxrDLt-gP06NQjdDwjRDD8AibCvBJ01oAAZSRMALAFAEgAUVnWQSIznX8B8DIrInIvIihVRZIIohTeoJISgkITI8oCo-Ip3KwsvZpIwqIw0S2ZDZo7I3ItogPcbTo2FC7Yok%20YIkAAY1oqonxRI-w7o4o0JDfJo8ooY%20YhiRuWonTGKRomYjYyogo3vLo1wwI%20oaMMolozYgo5ws4vbFI%20oa4MQM-ZSWY242PNXJI5Yuo7wdvfoo44Y-NcsXYl5BZa4wY442PAwqfc4p4uUCBSEuYk3F3bA5InonQEQmIoRD46EgPCIsY7FDnP4-0DrOjPE4ExNKMIPdE34nTOoc8ZEz4gkxYww%20EzE9yPg9Ym4-EkExiMElLZzZkvk6kvsU48Yp7BEqObkw43kqkyFczQU8VXxRuEUhU49WyIkvtFvYFdrNYuUqEjU4%20AKZUjNG4A4ykrY25WEukjk4ou%20S0oE605KE9M0zWMYA0q06-BoD-OEx4zEsYYUdUl0qad082WHN4xcb08fUvc%20B4iYv4i0nEqBGMxvcXf0xMnTCBDw8kNMnvcM-hMQFM9450n0%204yUkknTAKEM6-FfbU89BPcVfU2soAvw9kgMyY-jVst-W0lwzspMyQck3EssoAtE-srM8Ep0%20U0Mi1Qs31KM4MfM5fWkicqUzE96Es6M0ct-NkzM9c4ojhZAnsuAjMu0gcnTJIGbE85fCU4k83DlF46co02cvGCs%208ps-7X-CkncjzOteckDAHG8%20g9s-cqsspIfQEmc6-HtBs59NfPUlzZc%20g8chMg8v4xkr038kgv088yclLX04C49GQVctC8CjlbMYc1M7C%20gvcvC9ChksjZ8lE8fGQM8tc8i8VXwLC6C1iu8nUhCzWL7JCmi4i98gS0AqNSC5uZC49QrACimLcpc0S4%20U9OCkzQSj3E9Ii1Svssih86rIHEc3izg1Cysgy4FdBKi0sky4Q3CjiiyiWIcnS-%20K8hSxhJSvMlS1yuihyz8pynCaY2S1S9i-S-y82JEqCl86-Bo9y-4AqKKlizg8Sxs3UiWbsxKlkjzZAuKrnTyqgYK-%20HwUC%20iziwbXMgq7y5%20NeXKuUbXFy6q%20ysKtK4hKOBq2BMjWq3xaSn82yuLfjWq4s9q-mKWWquBYahWGKLq2HCavWIzdSjXTSwuRuZQzK0UwzEqvylqpA%20eWa5KBdWqobParMAHQa784y6K8fbXWqgRY6sqavQ6866ivqtdNvWqmata40-%20Rkrqoy56y6zLWHWq68z618uBMyj87ahuIa0G6-UJM6kSl649XBBa8QpgimJ6mygGjzHbVGyXHg9paYgAMRQEUEUCcHaL0vMvCsLivPypCBJrJoppGIhoksQPnTYpc0ZvJoKKaupqhpA1PgNO5uZv5NGPjP5qWvkleQqoZtJp5vaN8uaqlrLS5VlJFoKNCslskqrzI2ssXA1vaP4tSpVrQQBGJvltFrFN8Vqq5TsOQ0NoJO%20KWPtIwoHkXPJEdv5NNzxpwIuJKP7DWi9rFP7FtvQQ9qoGDsVOd0OvdQtqZpNz5shtNtsN8H1uDCjvNRpNqsKztiDstpNyVu1vZpAwaF8XzoTtjy1uTp1vnVCXVoLtj2Nvgtrp-H2PTs9sboJJSpbpLrQS%202Fq7pL2do7PwtbyUwjrlsrsb02uVtboxr-XjoVsbypprr7qu0rkHunpL1ZpNvnpbAWUnpAEzpNKTrZokPAV9Ibu3ri2hV9oxOKN2EiubhPv-jjKAT3vXq8AaK4wdqHtvurvPvRtsMworuXoLPvvpJeXf1luPv-rXWzEGvngONfufnrIlrXovsQwgWvvAeX1nuLqwZbBig7sjvgePXxhzsnVwatrXVbC6qjlgdQdgXf2BuCxobrNIsIeAeGg%20pfvIbdSLswZ4cSDzr-pvrocAc-qIcUzprAdoYoebo0v3q8H4yf3EbwboZ7uUa-sNHAPkZgpHrAscqjRwnprgYkeIoIeEYJtsLhiPuYf5lgowaAdsaFDXnMccYVknTGqTw0YUYnTPukZEd0znAMdYq4ZsbcNOSmJQYEf-gES6rtvCcyzYsGrI08fieflIMgddp0zEBm1Ians0bEveoKY4fH3ktyYvPyz1pSeEOsdceidSNhwqc4NXqaf9oKe538Zit3t7pkazABP4csdUqCYGZCZuGkHqbkMic6YRI4WGboy8b1hEK6pwjidGdcqkYmbcbUCoS5qydgViuqbHv%201bCXoCdcu0cWpUcNFPwcaOZGqMdKpMZbT7AUm0t6fH2KuBsxoNqecmo6eCb2blAok2ZKePhqtOYYrKW1yZO%20cyw0JhbKvSr00ReyrmZBeaeeJITaeyqEfmc5Mbi3shaKp2Z0cGahRmfUKUdud0cln9Hxf6pubRtBYBwSRpePXmpcexf9ruVWpGbJefjsxRbeZnDLsea2ZFeBd2ZxewkOeldgRITGr%20uUhWf2tZfxvlZJa5ePkaEevFMVeFdgVOrFZpolbIz1e%20tlcpZCYKcyaVf5muvNYFsHX%20YzsBb1iJC6peMFeWa9eSgUiSYfEuevx%20tdZTsJGu39aEQ1aGcab5YRPqoxbK1tfpapbbx6aFauefia0jbuYtg9c7qdYVkWwLYZec1jagXjbKhtorapfPDrWtc%20xea2qjfgDYpbbB36btdBeZfu0JaTY3N-pzfCK1b9uTeLaoAAFEAAPKAVgDHGRLgGoDAUQSm96k%20NaedxdgXFdtdjdlmhhvx5uXdpdjAA9rYdd3mrq14lzc9-d1d69o9sWrFuV-2m4Apndhdi9q9jwG9xWsOnCH9vd5d59gD1962iljNkJxk0o5DR98Dw9k4963xaYpDy9iDvgKD6O%20t3lj9hZteIpkATD-9nDk3NtuehltvfGUDv97DwDgkxNwjwMmbAWejp9lDmEnOnCA0sjxj3DrOmOhtkJkheBTj5Dl9xOw65ByTrD7jgk99vt%20Vv9EyRD39rj6T2PId1jw8hZFAqBATxT72mDtlnVgHWB4z7Tgkul8zz9sug46zyDjPaaq1jTsDhTmz4eu9%209%20T8jpjkvFjlTrp0%20IkfzwTn09N%20zhEn%20h9zTqTlz2M3t2D0Fv8b2CLkz2%208ZkL5NydDDhLrzpLxvZT1L%20Vl4xoTL7z2%203T3Ljck9fjwrgLoTk0sz7Vz96vKzpryL2Muz9rhZw1eBI%205zij2Midh%20v4w1CEjzhjrLuhqj7htL%20eWUkbwL-B96tbKr4ruA6L-r%20r6dkIVblr-%20eh0T0F6ySrmbrT7b5fHLsrz9nBxrzz5rzhw6w1cxo7us2r%2075Nv9Fb7rubihtrydjcxhrb0bt-PrkH4o4LNVxcT7oA8bqBlLWH8Htb%20ghbqJrpgeAr57nr1J4Ln7zE7XNIq7xLiHv83b6HpM-jGssnorinkglLmLwM-LtH477Ju7ln-Tmvenl7iJrqqhBo9nmC777nyb6vEjhH1J4HibpzF44bgH6r%20gqHuX-LBJDhEX1ipHvJuFhZIWrXzgzHolmH%20eLrvHwH1Swn8Xpzf0Qz5SaX4QqntXjld6Q7Q34Q5nvblYtvRXi35XuSrn73v45Anac32bgP1S0rm39Xv9J7iPm7tdNZs7%20V%20BBrj3uQ2X5HlU1seL-3xPuS1X7PjNYsjKs9pXgv1SnXmpiigEKXivxn9Q434dyYwreP67xv49X5lP7Hy3Pn-H7K534vj0y78v-PzvqFr36nhkjhev8f9HrvoP6fuFuGdv8nhfqF6P4P-Jk9e3%20HhvjfoqsX7f-Lb2OfhPif8lnO14v3i-w-6qov3X131sJzg-jnjq6vs5iWfGXHu-9--mHlh-T05-Fiy03Mfn-2vyisCOdXFYnclf7z9-%20CsCiMDQEQfc3%20kAqfi71bzBYM%20hmJflgL1ILo1%20DPe-sqy37L8OUbFf7ggMgHH8KB1Watg73QHj4Xi6zKtrgO5aP8a%20DAvouAI76kCABn-WFiliWZCJHecWA1j32TYcD9W1vE-hRQQ58D1%20iA71kPyf4qlG4jJGQd9UwHD8IysOPfsGHEGvV8Beg2mve1v78CVBQbcgQQPSrRh4BEAq6nQLsHmwRC2g5%20G9SkHE9umHg01lwK-4Rkzk-fS3t9SEGotiECScPlYLhpyD6Bepd6OfxiHj5Xih1TONEOUFw1dB6g-7B4z8H8x54ttayPkJwS2CzBM4RIRkJIHWChmLg8oSBnPCGDyQxg5GlnxyFCUmEefJwZlkkBIMkhmQ8fL1m8HFEjsIQyPv-CoTvV%20h1Q6-IUWGGTcHwlggYZlgBDvUDupHZgSsNMHtCk4urMYZXwmF1Cdh-CNvCUL1g7F5hexDhD-H2GX9KEAQ4QSqUYH78aBgw8IeKxAxdDkhmWXGtAKJ7FEIEv-b4TjWyHcCM0X2OnkoJmHj5CSfwmPq7xBpQj%20ePwo4WCM1juDbhAghWHHkuFlJ0EXw5YTjXeEWt%204zwowU1y0DyAAADuu2gCGBZyowNQWiNWwEjL2lImkcwDpF-xSoowUEYELDxw9yRz3dkbSKgD0jb2uIygS8WIEyIRRnIsUdyOqLi0gBMApMgCDQHCj0cHIrkQyLZySic%20wZPnnKJ1Ga0km1efzsaIVG6jy2cI%20Qc2XC5GitRoo8Ue0WJFutU6VCDUX%200tEuina01HqmIIpFOj5Rvo72nENcHLVK4Xo-dj6MVHzImR-IhuAkmoHejgxJo2PHyMeF6k7YKYmMWmKtEyd9RGaQ7KyNlH5jQxIdMoccIqHu9HR1I50XGPiSojEx4CQ1JCLoxkdYxuonEbaPiEw5tcTQ2dkGPrEhjGx94B4REOWpRwlhbI8sWOPXBuiO2cAE%20I4LzEjj0xjeZvsAOzLP0Oxw47UQWNjLhj6hyENvIVgtFziwadyXjtMLLHrjDxjeTMZOPkjrDOxl4n0tsOZFTi%20Ge4zUfeIrEIMqxX4%20SLzyRFdifSzYrMUJVzHLtwJsZNocBJAxlhoxsE98b11toOiwJaExvIuMLZ3JBxh3fcQ2LBroMVR-wjChlzrEHiAJFDY8dWP7jh4qJxEusgmKglRp3opYuCW-ifEfD2knE7CXAU-EtjEM9tLCf%20PnFewgJwkmJvxPEkkTIJz4pQjKK4mnk-msk6iRJKTRrD1JzExHv6IIkbC-xGksGv%20SLFgEbhYk4yTBTomISKYo7X8amLkkwUhJbE5aoiIclrirJrFBSbxNOTqNLJukmXoLx0mjiTJE43yYplfFETQpMVGydJOihAjUJTkypjxJJGDoB4F45KZwRcmKSMaIUjccIR8lpSzwGUpiTFMqYIT4p8AeyYGKMmBThC4U4qZFPykPjsqcU1yTxCliZSvJSLHKRFMNAzi7xPUgljnXPFlSCp-VRqe6O-oGS3xWUjzC617ERiG4hWDDlSMqKLA7ABRViblPGQBijO60gUJtIKKpTppagfjA%200Ono5pEEopaSeMYSnDEOV046e0SkkdT0Y8CTXk9I2k3SgOZk82LTx3bPTfpIxSqe9MUp0dvpR0kGWLSmlLjGSJFIGT9K2mui72NwNacjMo7A1V%20SM6GSjOY451KKuM66fjO9o7T%20pksOcFL2BmkyQ6p0pcVeS%20zEyXpBJPqU1PqDZhZpNMk3G9N2khI-wzMmGSHSKlnSi4-GKztzKrq21J0EszGU3VtpSx%20Oks7uoTLviCzaZCDLcaqMvLwIMZeMn0u1L5lvR4s6sqLus12DUy5Zj4rqlGOG7KyS8bM0We1hhpnt7Zt9XmRTPniKCOxbshBiLIZldSoZJMn0mDKNk7BdgSsq2RAzun0TTxG4MRq7Kjm31cJDLDiXbKTnzckmFkn2RnNoldV%20Mc%20IOSzJ27pNxqRcoWXQ3pmFtYc2bHOfrKAKOylxxVdzonPrlv4PZ7M7wMkFNlAF-ZhbRuMUPLkaygeg1MurLLblwE4ZhbApnch7lv4U5jbTenPL-JazyJOmOcCt19lWM1hp7OucHNYrkzO5HCdFq3P3mpMq5NHL5qfOLkkEO5ossYK%20K3kTpQ5FMzCXvJvkq9BqjJPWWfL-ILyQmACZeXIVXnwjW8F0oBUn0NkUzZA6cieXIUPmizv5sC3%20XIQvlUtgh18iuYHyKGbzc5UfHOlrCHkxU%205lbMkc0KflH9sZTnChTK3WavFcFcCwzP-PO6jDMFw8-Vo3OnlkLZ2NC01i-KPkMKUFa6fNjHNsnkRQk3Cw7rwoKF3z4ZnQy6XgsawkLG28iiBcjWYWp8hsj8xRZQigWdz2sArBRYwssIIKlxXszoWoqcK8dJFpHaRdiJAV2jixTCdyWILsV6xQ6-05arDgsVEKYRU81Oaot8U-CNF-tH8WIJEAeAAAjmgAgAABra0aYsLanwd2ESngNEriXWi0FkzRkk51SXpL4lt0siaAuBS%20kapRnPJTEoKWvSbqiMxDhUoyUFFlFkzFaikuYBRLKl1o-haLIgS5K2laSjpah08UVDowtc8JX0vyXWiQlCJd6LsAUitL2lDSr4kkx2jzL%20liygmUMp-D4wy6H3epVUoJKJKGWUcB9nsu7FZL%202hWKzqcsLGiKqp3gAeKBI7HXLY8si6ea8XgQnLxlAynTqPIaLDdnlBJLpUuPNqzSAV3tfxegvPBhM6lXy9Zd7SmUblCFZ7MFbfQcV9jdhgOVZRMoNljVT8GHFFQg0OWZsxgoK2Ffsp3ppCVuBKzUpwqOUCJSVCy8le7LvYvEsV3yxvE0vO59hkJbKuFQAz%20ZzKYVjKq8RCvtZ-gpe1Kk0giuKIvF38%20KslSRLRXLT%204ZSh3pKpO56LRZ97ZJUKrWVMq6GRKkJlLF3ljLhVdZc5TqyoS9KzVDcsanKt5X6qKGryhlqfgdXyTBqNwXZQqrrJArp5LS3VdiqAKiqluvAp5d6r0mbK3IAiT5TatSZKr7pQoYUgGvZV-lNVZi41VcvDWpNDV7LaMF6tjV-kLVXTSdDZAlVZq-ytKxtq2kenIry1t8wakpnzV6qTJnK%20VodkzUFqSCvqytlLGzmmrm1MFYNZasDrJq%20V9BaVX8Sjih83VMVeNbHPGREh5VnayBes3fxNrA17TNgUuoHUpTBqvgDtTuuyk51-JYa5dXJWdWZs35-ajdYVIYavj1Vz8eQpGrPAcSGVh6hqbxxnWVMJ1TmABPxwfUdU51Yit9NupvX9U01by-5XWvUI5rVONkUDSmv6pFrpSGI2tWeqhaVqAFx5UdY6s34bdGJaG99f1VbXFqkVp6ojeoW7XoLxOX6pFkOs-aHYy16Goqj%20tP6CrCNYGwzEBruV00qV0G7lhBsrZjAGi66xDYZlg3%200RCCGsddy2Q2YlFZ0m3Df-D-CHUT01qijdywvWTNT4J88jZxu5YkaESJCGtXprE3csqNITNilevKX8bj4B1Z9dETfX6a7NrGkQb4Fo0LTuN4M7YCIRGUeaJBgmxeXxuY2eC5NKxYLRpo4WjSOEMayLd9S00sLT4EW5zd9UM2BkRNsWlLZ4Is2gsY2yWszfq3o1EccBOGsGkDQc3VSNe-m4RV5rDkKQyN16grY1kC0hMRC-62zY1gk3TKNwX7arcjTC2Dk%20tx8QoRVslhwghtjWBLfK0nRQaQtsCeGqNqDLa4D1WW%20bTluHWZamtebVzTnx8UcattsCSYYtpwjNtStswrrYGRPiqr4eAG-mB0VuXebhoAUfLTJp6xTbP2Oq-ba9sOH5zNt32yhOtv5aiCbNc2u7TtozQyyJtrbQ6jcBe1KbPsLW3LUdTO0wiLtKxYjuptW38wzso2xkiejh1g1YRRSxxU5XMVQ6wcaWx%20jYpna3bsRgO2LiRVm1xbPsRWwMuYwAAizAAwAAHMeAUAQpVhjXlwsDSnOnnXzruII11houtALzv52x5Ed8rDnVzpl3i6Mx01EjtLtl03Lid6KtyQZM12q6lOttFzAbrl2skxqa0U3Sbnp3yaeVyGK3fLNG0Ep7dyurXbHnB3f8Tdruw3T51x3C8XdYus3UFzOqW7vdQe2%20mjsnUmahEDuxvKzpWI2LY9cBWrZ7JK3Nwk963RbfiND2B6WJ01BrVAgz2VzbaGusPa91G0SKc9Ku8PXQ0p2TcYo4CgPdXp9WDU1ZTet3ZD3WbeKvdue1iinqPlK7e9BPHOtMSL3EV3tCzbMFLrL3eT1me2ujGPt0rWKq9Hez3sbun1D67Kv28zCvp92zNHqu%20mvbJu0kb7m9LAuvb%20sCXp6Z9mWVgYtq0U96z9t%20j3UnHn0x6b9HmYsifsT0f6ys8ewclfoX2-7hFL%20najNlP2r64s%20HHXcqtvjI7r9m%2007KAehoNFlCAAXSqAAASLAHYD4DyBYAIQPnVACpFYA4AAAejINo5udEAAAHTc6yAPANAAACMaDJARQGQZwN4GIAlBjANQYAC0uRLQJQZ8A0GAAVlgGUC9A2gKAbQCAHZ2CgZEDALnfIBkTc7SaTB1ADIkIBcjNDYAEgFgERxaBmAOAKIHkXuD4jUQGAEgFroDoKARAsSwYBQBpFUA7ALAOwDId6CKAqR8iPMBIBoMOpOhHCOBNGHKw2BF2igApSECYMoB5EDhkoOEfiW0AwAz4KoEQAcB6HCA3OwYHO0GBMAMA9AKgOGE4CkAMcAAVSkT86Qg9IYo%20QGcMhB2RigTkSgF6AQA52%20hwYNzuYB5F4ADAVALYGcBVBggoAPIwUZCCLwajdRkAIQEUAYhUALRto14FADSHZDIAAYyUBIAAAvbQMMZID5GKgp0CY7IfSXAhoAZiU4MsaoAABBQgOYE0MABxdQ5ofkOZhOAMh7nUQAqCgB3DJAKkQAAkrDNhj6jYAkQeHYgnIzIxgARw5GxtymKoA4FJpGAdjexqgOMZABOHZD0x2Y80deO8GPj8AcwCgBQADHnAQAA).

Can anyone help me understand why?  I've noted an increasing tendency of Vega-Lite examples to use ISO-8601, and in fact if I change this example to use that format it works.  So this is more of a 'why *isn't* it working with datetime'.  Is this format still recommended? Does it still even work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies but I think I misled you with my comment on the other thread (now deleted). Date time objects are only used for filter transform, scale domain, and axis/legend values. I have looked through all the sample json files for Vega Lite and can find no example of specifying a data object like you do in your sample.

Instead, if you specify you data as follows, you don't need to provide a format object.

```
{"entity": "Wildfire", "date": "2022-10-01", "deaths": 75}
```